# How to calculate bootstrap Resistor in MC34163 Buck configuration

Tags: buck, step-down, bootstrap

I am designing a DC-DC buck converter with [MC34163DWG](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/MC34163_D-2315604.pdf). I try to understand what value of resistor RB must I use at the buck/step down configuration and I also have questions about the CB capacitor. Page 10:

[image: DC-DC buck MC341 Resistor]

The datasheet says I need to make sure the capacitor's ESR (or an external resistor) to be of a value that limits the 7V internal Zener's current to <100mA. And then it gives me a formula to calculate the minimum CB value. Page 9:

[image: MC34163DWG CB RB resistor value]

So I need to know what the voltage will be across CB to calculate the RB value to use to limit the current to <100mA. As I try to calculate it, I made some assumptions and thoughts. Let me know if what I thought of is right:

I started from their CB(min) calculation:
[image: CBmin Dc-DC]
They assume \$(I=4mA, ΔV=4V)\$, where I is the current flowing from the capacitor CB in pin 16 and its split in two: to the Zener and the 2mA current source. So their resistor RB is limiting the current at 4mA. Now why is \$ΔV=4mA\$? I assume because their Vin is 12V, Vzener is 7V so the voltage across the CB should be \$(12Vmax-7V=) 5V\$ minus losses + Rsc resistor Vdrop + RBVdrop so they assumed/measured 4V. From that calculation I understand that they need a capacitor large enough to keep current flowing through it as long as the switch is on.

Now to calculate my RB, at pins 14,15, the voltage will be \$Vin=21V\$ in my case.
So the voltage across CB will be \$(21V-7Vzener=) 14V\$. So I need to limit the current @14V to be less than 100mA. I assume 4mA must be enough (as the example's calculations with CB). The RB should be \$R=V/I=14V/0.004A=3k5Ω\$.

If my assumption is correct, the output voltage is independent of the calculations regarding the RB. In that case they could add a formula to the datasheet to calculate the \$RB=(Vin-7V)/~4mA\$.

1. I want to know if my assumptions/calculations are correct for the RB and CB.
2. Regarding the capacitor CB, why do they show a polarized capacitor with its positive side at the pin 16? pin 16 goes from 0 to 7V max, while pin 15 (aka the other side of CB) goes from 0V to Vin (I assume). I would use either a ceramic cap there or a polarized cap but opposite polarization to what they show.
   [image: Polarized cap]
3. What is the "0.02" written above the CB, RB?
   [image: what is 0.02]
4. Last but not least, how do I know that my bootstrap CB, RB are correct once I have my PCB soldered? Where should I probe on the circuit and what should I see on both cases (if my bootstrap is wrong and if my bootstrap is correct)?

Comment: Look at the block diagram again. The zener at pin-16 has its anode connected to + which probably implies the positive rail. So the voltage at pin-16 is clamped to input voltage plus 7V.

Comment: @RohatKılıç You are right! In page 3 datasheet says "Bootstrap Input Zener Clamp Voltage:, VZ typical value is VCC + 7.0V , where VCC is the input voltage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the resistor value towards the minimum, so more like 150 or 200 ohms.

The average voltage on the right of Cb is 5.05V and the voltage on the left is between Vcc and Vcc+7, so the polarity is correct. They used a somewhat unconventional symbol for the Vcc connection that can be mistaken for ground at a quick glance.

0.02 is the capacitance- 20nF or 0.02uF.

You can measure the peak voltage across the resistor and test the circuit at the corners of min/max input voltage and output current to ensure there is typical margin.

Comment: Hm. Why the voltage on the right of the Cb is 5.05? I assume this IC switches its output (Pins 14,15) on/off from Vin (21V in my case) to GND so I thought that would be the voltage at the right of Cb.

Comment: It has to average the same as the output voltage (ignoring the DC current times inductor DCR), right?

Comment: May I know, how did you figure out that the 0.02 is 0.02uF? Is there a standard when no measurement units are used, the default is uF? And even, how you know its the capacitor's value and not the resistor's? I mean.. it could be 200 Ohms... (which makes less sense)

Comment: @ChristianidisVasilis Default is uF. 0.02nF would be ridiculously low- it has to supply a couple mA to the boostrap circuit.  It's a buck converter- so you know the theoretical waveform at the Rb-L-diode node is a Vin/0 square wave at the switching frequency (about 45kHz). In reality it will be a bit less than Vin on the high side due to the transistors' drop and the current sense resistor, and will go negative by the Schottky diode drop.

Comment: You can simulate this with the internal Zener and the internal current sink if you want to see the peak Zener current etc.

Answer (score 0):

@Sphero is right, I checked the Pin 16 (Bootstrap input) with the oscilloscope:

[image: Bootstrap input MC34163]

The voltage goes from 19V (my Vin) to 28V (Vin + 7V).

But you see there's ringing due to the fast/violent switching. I needed to use a bootstrap resistor of higher value (1k) to reduce the ringing:

[image: Much cleaner bootstrap R]