# What are the consequences of small bootstrap resistor (in DC-DC buck/step down specifically)?

Tags: buck, step-down, bootstrap

If I understand it correctly, a bootstrap capacitor (CB) is used to store energy to turn on the high-side MOSFET (P-channel MOSFET). In DC-DC buck converters (which I use now) this happens several times per second as the IC switches.

I do not understand what problem does a bootstrap resistor (RB) solves and/aka what happens in my circuit if I use a lower value resistor (or 0 Ω resistor).
I understand the drawback of using a RB, which is that it limits the current that goes in the CB, increasing the time it takes for CB to charge and RB also wastes some current (transforming it in heat).

I read [here](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/and9674-d.pdf) something that is close to answering my question:

> Unfortunately, the series resistor does not provide a foolproof
> solution against an over voltage and it slows down the recharge
> process of the bootstrap capacitor.

-Where does that "overvoltage" might occur? I assume, on the circuit I use with [MC34163DWG](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/MC34163_D-2315604.pdf), at pin 16 (where RB is the bootstrap resistor):

[image: MC33163 Buck configuration]

I did a previous question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/675919/how-to-calculate-bootstrap-resistor-in-mc33163-buck-configuration) on how to calculate the value of the resistor, but I still have that knowledge gap.

-The title is the question.

Comment: What is the diagram from? Please cite sources for figures used. || AND9674 looks to be largely MOS bootstrap type drivers, can you show a passage from this document that applies specifically to this IC, or similar circuits? || Do you know what defines the current through a capacitor? The explanation quoted in the other question seems clear enough to me, but the key to your question seems to be something more fundamental.

Comment: Maybe if you use 0R, it damages the 7.0V internal zener on pin 16. The supply voltage is 12v, and when the switch is on, you should see almost the same voltage on pins 14 and 15. From the look of it, that switching voltage will pass the CB and reaches the zener.

Comment: Typically, the bootstrap resistor is used to reduce the peak current provided to the high side driver, slowing the turn-on of the switch and reducing ringing and EMI on the switch node.  It's the ringing that can cause overvoltage on the switch.  It has the added benefit of reducing the peak current in the bootstrap diode.  Of course the RC time constant has to be small enough to allow charging at minimum duty cycle.  With this particular part there may be other reasons as well for the recommendation, as @Saadat posits.

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect: the bootstrap capacitor is not necessary if the high-side MOSFET is p-channel, because a p-channel FET is turned on with a gate voltage *below* its source voltage. Bootstrapping is only needed if the high-side FET is n-channel (or if it's an npn BJT, if your controller is old enough), which needs a gate voltage *higher* than the source to turn on.

Comment: All right thank you for leading me to the right direction. I see there is a "Bootstrap Input Current Range" and "Bootstrap Input Current Source" in the datasheet. And for the possible Ringing notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I think I got it. Thank you for the help in the comments I was able to figure it out. Testing my [MC34163DWG](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/MC34163_D-2315604.pdf) hookup as shown in the question (but with Vin=20V), I was able to capture some oscilloscope pics with a 150R bootstrap resistor (left images) and a 1k bootstrap resistor (right images).
[image: Wrong (low) Bootstrap resistor consequences]

I consider the 1k resistor to be a good value here since:

1. The Datasheet mentions in the maximum ratings 100mA max current in bootstrap input:
   [image: max current bootstrap]
   and
2. The nominal current in the bootstrap input is 2mA, 4mA max.
   [image: current bootstrap resistor]

So since the Bootstrap input goes from 20V to 27V (I assume 30V), with 1k I get 3mA flow in the bootstrap input. Which, looking at the oscilloscope plots I show above, clearly shows that the ringing has been removed.

As @Saadat and @John D said in the comments, the resistor is there for protection of the zener diode and to remove the ringing. The consequences of using a lower resistor value are ringing and a probably damaged zener diode in the IC. On the other hand, using a very high resistor wont let enough current to flow in the capacitor CB during charging and the power wont be enough to turn on the N-Channel mosfet (Thank you @Hearth in the comments).